# How do I change color every time my length is bigger then 5 character in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can turn my color into green when my length exceed more then 5 characters. I keep getting "object doesn't support this property" error

```
   Sub deme()

     Dim lastrow As Long
     Dim a As Integer
     a = 1
     Dim cc As String
     Dim i As Long

       lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
          For i = a To lastrow

          cc = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i)
            If Len(cc) > 5 Then
                   Worksheets("sheet1").Character(cc, i).Font.Color = vbRed

             End If




         Next i


  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Character(cc, i).Font.Color = vbRed
```

I changed it to

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).Font.Color = vbRed
```